# PDO construct in case of failure

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using this kind of pdo connection function:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO{

    const DB_HOST='localhost';
    const DB_PORT='3306';
    const DB_NAME='testdb';
    const DB_USER='root';
    const DB_PASS='root';

    public function __construct($options=null){
        parent::__construct('mysql:host='.MyPDO::DB_HOST.';port='.MyPDO::DB_PORT.';dbname='.MyPDO::DB_NAME,MyPDO::DB_USER,MyPDO::DB_PASS,$options);
    }

    public function query($query){ //secured query with prepare and execute
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args); //first element is not an argument but the query itself, should removed

        $reponse = parent::prepare($query);
        $reponse->execute($args);
        return $reponse;

    }

}
```

Now the connection and query works fine and everything is great, but in case if mysql server is down the script i'm using this connection function just stops working. Instead i would like it to return some message in case if mysql server did not respond or mysql settings are set wrong.

I've tried doing something like

```
if(new MyPDO===false){echo "The database is down currently. Please try again later."}
```

But that doesn't work. Please help me out.
All i need is to show a message in case if mysql connection is unavailable instead of breaking whole script and showing a blank page ( like it is currently ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a try catch in your parent class when constructing your PDO should work:

```
try{
   //your pdo construction
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);  
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error"; // you could also add $e->getMessage(); to display a message why your try catch returned false
}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
if($yourpdovar instanceof PDO) {
   //succeeded message.
}else{
   //error message
}
```

This code checks if your variable is a PDO variable. It's simple and you can put it everywhere in your code.

Comment: With try catch should i close connection after end of the code ? For example , atm anywhere where i need db connection i do $db = new MyPDO; some codes and query etc , and than $db = null; so i dont leave any connections open

Comment: Nevermind , keeping using $db=null as usually at end of the code. Everything works great

Answer (score -1):

From the PHP PDO [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Catch the error and do whatever you want. Render a page, display an error, redirect, whatever.

Comment: You should include an explanation of the code and what it does, not just a code sample as an answer.

Comment: It may seem so to you @gnarly, but you have to make sure all of your answers are clear an explained well not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: All the OP needs to do is catch the error and deal with it. Not much more to say.